# Razer Surround must be always connected?

Tags: audio-hardware

*Razer Surround* comes together with *Razer Synapse* software, and *Synapse* asks me to connect everytime Windows starts. If I do not connect, will *Razer Surround* work?

If I close *Razer Synapse*, will *Razer Surround* still work?

Comment: Shouldn't this kind of question be asked on [Superuser](http://superuser.com/) instead? Besides, can't you just not connect / close *Razer Synapse* and see if *Razer Surround* still works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will work.

Online mode is for syncing your settings to Razer's servers... or the "cloud" as everyone likes to say these days.

You can choose to go offline by clicking on the drop down arrow at the top right. It shouldn't prompt once you're offline.